# what is usage of parsing mibs?

Tags: snmp, mib

Can anyone tell me why NMS implementations parse and save MIB items in a database?

I know one of the reasons is when they receive a trap and want to analyze it, then they use the parsed MIB. What else they do with parsed MIB?

For example, when the NMS sends a SNMP GET request to an agent, the programmer must specify which OIDs are being requested?

Does the the parsed MIB have a another purpose or do we parse MIBs only for analyzing SNMP traps?

Comment: my guess is just to make them easier to work with and caching performance.  Since DB lookups way faster than searching and parsing the mib each time.  Easier to work with ,  especially for the operator of the software.   Way easier to search for something like `UpsOverload` as opposed to `.1.3.6.1.4.1.318.0.2`.

Comment: thanks for reply. but it was not the answer of my question. my question is developers parse mibs and by parsing, change it to a format to save it in a database.right? now i do not get why developers save mib objects (oids) in database? what is the use of that in developing NMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track - you parse the MIB *at all* in order to make it human-readable. That is for both traps (informs) and polled values. But if you parse it out to a text file, that's a huge amount of data to read/grep through to find out the description, message, possible values, related OIDs, etc.

Added to this is that there isn't just one MIB. There are dozens or hundreds that an NMS may be interested in. Since, on a host, you only add the MIBs that you want that host to respond to, the NMS has to have a copy of every MIB that ever device it is monitoring may have on IT so that it can understand the response the host returns.

So you parse each MIB and store it in a db to make it faster to search and to have everything all in one place. That could be so that you can find the messages associated with varbinds, or what all the possible enumerations are, etc.

Just to be clear, parsing the MIB isn't the same as doing an SNMPWalk on a host. SNMPWalk just gives you the current response to each OID in sequence.